# Joining two RDDs without common key based on a function in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to match user logins with the closest city in an efficient manner.

Starting with two RDDs with the following:

- RDD1: checkin_id ,user_id, session_id, utc_time, timezone_offset,
  latitude, longitude, category, subcategory
- RDD2: City_name, lat, lon, country_code, country, city_type

I would like to join these two to the following format based on the *closest* city as calculated by the haver-sin function.

- checkin_id ,user_id, session_id, utc_time, timezone_offset,
  latitude, longitude, category, subcategory, City_name, country

In Scala I do this with a double for loop, but this is not allowed in Spark. I have tried to use the Cartesian( rdd1.Cartesian(rdd2) ) and then reducing, but this gives me a massive N*M matrix.

Is there a faster more space efficient way of joining these RDDs based on the shortest haver-sin distance?

Comment: Don't think there's anyway you can get around doing a cartesian product -- for every login you have to calculate the distance to every city, which means sort of by definition you need to do a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to completely avoid the `join`. Assuming that `#cities` << `#user` (in other words `RDD1.count` << `RDD2.count`) the most efficient approach to simply `map` over users:

- convert `RDD2` to a local data structure
- convert it to a format which can be used for efficient geo-spatial queries (for example a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)
- `broadcast` it and use for mapping

If RDD2 is to large to be stored in memory but is small enough to be passed using a single file you can easily adjust this approach by replacing local data structure with solution like [SpatiaLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite):

- write data to as database
- distribute it to workers using standard Spark tools (`SparkFiles`)
- map over users using queries over local database

Finally, if none of the above works for you, be smart about the way you `join`:

- you can easily use latitude and longitude to map from user position to some local entity like a continent, country, local administrative entity. Use this information to perform initial join (obviously if user is somewhere in Europe checking Melbourne, Australia is pointless)
- use tools like GeoHash to assign users and cities to a buckets which can be used for joins (it will require some adjustments in border cases - you may have to put a single object into multiple buckets if it is located near the equator or 180 degree meridian).

Comment: Zero323, thank you! This is just what I have been looking for, and you assume correct that the cities RDD is much smaller than the check-in RDD.

I will look into K-d trees and local data structures in Spark. Initially I have been using the "Broadcast" to send the cities data locally to all the workes. However I faced I roadblock only being able to call .value from the file I broadcasted. How can this be used for mapping without a common key? 

Disclamer: I'm a student without prior experience with spark or large data processing

Comment: If I use RDD2 as a condition for a mapping on RDD1 I get a an error basicly saying "Can not do a mapping based on another RDD"

Comment: `broadcast` -> use `broadcast.value`. You cannot broadcast RDD (I guess this is what you mean by use RDD2 as a condition for a mapping). No nested actions or transf. are allowed.

Comment: Files -> [see `SparkFiles`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$) (`get` in particular)

Comment: Thank you again Zero323, I had misunderstood the .value concept. Thanks for clearing that up. I will up-vote your answer as soon as I get enough points. This is my very first question here on SO.